# Unable to get access token in JWT Grant using docusign java sdk

Tags: docusignapi

I have tried the following -

ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();
apiClient.setOAuthBasePath(oauthBasePath);

OAuthToken oAuthToken =
apiClient.requestJWTUserToken(
appContext.getDocusignClientId(), impersonationIdGUID, scopes, fileContent, 3600);

It is giving me the following error -
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded type: javax.ws.rs.core.Form

I noticed that the jwt token getting generated is perfect

Answer (score 0):

From what I found is that this is probably a RESTEASY library dependency issue.
try removing RESTEasy and checking if it would work.
If you can't seem to figure it out then feel free to open a ticket with DocuSign Developer Support, here: https://support.docusign.com/CSP_DSClogin?startURL=%2Fen%2FcaseOverview%3Fdfl%3D1